# Flask logging with Foreman

Tags: python, heroku, flask, foreman, procfile

I'm trying to set up a Heroku-ready Flask app, but I can't figure out how to turn on logging.

Without Foreman, I could create a helloworld app as described in the [Flask tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/):

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    app.logger.debug('A value for debugging')
    app.logger.warning('A value for warning')
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

start it like so:

```
python hello.py
```

and have logging in stdout.

When I follow the [Heroku tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python), however, there's no `app.run` line:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    app.logger.debug('A value for debugging')
    app.logger.warning('A value for warning')
    return 'Hello World!'
```

And so I can't figure out how to run in debug mode and/or get logging output:

```
foreman start -p 5000
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn hello:app
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default logging configuration for Flask apps is different in debug vs. production mode.

In your first example you are in debug mode. In this case Flask defines a logging handlers that logs all messages with level `logging.DEBUG` or higher to `stderr`.

The second example is not in debug mode. When debug mode is not enabled Flask creates a logger object but does not add any handlers to it, so nothing is printed.

For Foreman and Heroku you need logs to be sent to `stdout` or `stderr`, so all you need to do is add a `StreamHandler` with the logging level of your choice:

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# log to stderr
import logging
from logging import StreamHandler
file_handler = StreamHandler()
app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set the desired logging level here
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    app.logger.debug('A value for debugging')
    app.logger.warning('A value for warning')
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Alternatively, if you prefer you can do none of this and just enable debug mode for the Foreman/Heroku controlled application, though this would not be something I'd recommend for a production app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

Comment: @Miguel- thanks, but this is only working for warning-level logging. debug-level logging is still not showing up. How do I run the app in debug mode with Foreman?

Comment: @Yarin: I have updated the code, I had the logging level set in the handler, not in the parent logger. I've also added a snippet that shows you how to set debug mode without calling `app.run()`.

Comment: @Miguel- Perfect- the single line `app.debug = True` was really all I needed.

Comment: @Miguel- I've ran into one problem with this- The app doesn't reload changes when setting debug like this. When running the app in debug mode without foreman I don't need to restart the app to see changes,  but for some reason I do with this. Any ideas?

Comment: @Yarin: the reloader is a feature offered by Werkzeug, which you are replacing with Gunicorn when you run under Foreman, so you don't have that. If you set your `Procfile` to use Werkzeug then you can start the app by calling `app.run(debug = True)` and then you get the reloader.